# Using a cursor with a stored procedure - Front End Software Error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am receiving an error trying to build a macro using a stored procedure with a cursor.

Some relevant details need to be included. This is for a document in an Electronic Health Records system. First, I develop the templates/tables, then I create document macros to pull all the information into the EHR documents. I have used stored procedures hundreds of times, so I know that it is the cursor that is causing it to fail.

All I do is pass in the parameters and it creates a grid on the document. Whether or not it is a limitation of the software that is used to create the documents, I don't know. I figured I would ask here to make sure my code is correct.

Here is my table:

```
txt_enc_id   enc_id_generate
12345        93847
12345        75430
12345        93946
```

I am passing in the enc_id on the document macro, which will match up to the txt_enc_id column, and I need a stored procedure to run for each of the enc_id_generate rows in that table

Here's what I have for my stored procedure:

```
@enc_id VARCHAR(36)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @enc_id_generate VARCHAR(36)

    DECLARE enc_id_cursor CURSOR 
    FOR
        (SELECT enc_id_generate 
         FROM my_table 
         WHERE txt_enc_id = @enc_id)

    OPEN enc_id_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM enc_id_cursor INTO @enc_id_generate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

        -- Here is the stored procedure that needs to run for each record. 
        -- The only parameter it uses is @enc_id_generate

        FETCH NEXT FROM enc_id_cursor INTO @enc_id_generate
    END

    CLOSE enc_id_cursor
    DEALLOCATE enc_id_cursor

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

When I try to create the macro, I pass in the @enc_id, click ok in the parameter window, and I am getting this error:

> Failed to update the macro builder window.
>   Cannot find table 0.

Do I somehow need to NOT have the stored procedure inside the cursor, and somehow call it to execute? I don't know how to do that. I am not a SQL guru, so forgive me if I have murdered this code. I do know that cursors should be used sparingly, but the table holding those Encounter IDs will rarely have more than 2 or 3 records.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any advice you may have.

Lyn

Comment: _SQL_ is the standard that most relational databases implement. _SQL Server_ is Microsoft's relational database product.

Comment: @Allan that was an accident - fixed thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You didn't show how you call your SP from cursor. `exec dbo.my_sp @enc_id_generate` As well does your SP happen to change `my_table`?

Comment: This is pretty clearly a question about the T-SQL procedural language that's a part of SQL Server, not SQL in the generic sense.